# Unable to upload large file using WebClient class in the ASP.NET C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, webclient

I need to upload a file to virus checking site using this code

```
public string Scan(string file)
{
    var v = new NameValueCollection();
    v.Add("key", APIKey);
    var c = new MyWebClient() { QueryString = v };
    
    c.Headers.Add("Content-type", "binary/octet-stream");
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    byte[] b = c.UploadFile(scan, "POST", file);
    string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(b);
    var r = ParseJSON(json);
    if (r.ContainsKey("scan_id"))
    {
        return r["scan_id"];
    }
    throw new Exception(r["result"]);
}
```

This code works fine with smaller files, but once I try to upload files of 50 MB size I get the exception

> The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

I did lookup this error and tried increase the maxAllowedContentLength and maxRequestLength values to 2147483647

It didn't help. No matter what I do, I always get the error mentioned above

Is there any way to upload the large file to a site using the WebClient class? Is there any other way to upload the larger file in the ASP.NET Web Forms?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The server policy is explicitly rejecting your payload due to size. If it's your server, you can adjust the limits. If not, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: When I go to a site directly, I am able to upload files with no problems using their UI (https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload)

Do you thing the UI and the WebClient use different settings?

Comment: I can't say for certain. If I understand correctly the only distinction between the success case and the failure case is the size of the file. Given that it is likely as you suggest that there that UI talks to a server endpoint that is differently configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have control over the 'remote server'? If not, you have no way to override what its maximum accepted file size is. This value will be configured on the receiving (remote) side.

Comment: When I go to a site directly, I am able to upload files with no problems using their UI (https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload)

Do you thing the UI and the WebClient use different settings?